# chrome failed to be started in jmeter docker container

Tags: docker, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I have created a docker image that has all the jmeter packages, libs packed together, and I was able to invoke some other jmeter test cases within my running container.

But for a special selenium jmeter test case, which requires the chrome running in headless mode, it fails as the chrome is not started (?)

Here are the version of my packages:

```
jmeter: 5.6.2
selenium-plugin on jmeter: 4.13
google-chrome: 120.0.6099.109
chrome-driver: 120.0.6099.109
```

I have checked the jmeter log, which says:

```
2024-01-10 16:50:36,994 ERROR o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Error calling threadStarted
org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Response code 500. Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Host info: host: 'aac0c7996ca3', ip: '172.17.0.2'
Build info: version: '4.13.0', revision: 'ba948ece5b*'
System info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '5.4.0-166-generic', java.version: '1.8.0_392'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Command: [null, newSession {capabilities=[Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: chrome, goog:chromeOptions: {args: [--remote-allow-origins=*, --start-maximized, --headless=new], binary: /usr/bin/google-chrome, extensions: []}, proxy: Proxy(system)}]}]
        at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:140) ~[selenium-remote-driver-4.13.0.jar:?]
```

I have googled this issue, and someone suggested to have the chrome started with such option:

```
--disable-dev-shm-usage
```

Is that possible I give the location of my google-chrome in my jmeter project, along with the running options ?

Thanks,

Jack

**UPDATES (01/11/2024).**

Thanks for the inputs. I have used your dockerfile and have made some adjustment and have gave a try, but the results stay the same.

Dockefile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

ARG JMETER_VERSION="5.6.2"
ENV JMETER_HOME /opt/apache-jmeter-${JMETER_VERSION}
ENV JMETER_BIN ${JMETER_HOME}/bin

RUN  apt update && apt upgrade -y \
     && apt install wget curl gnupg unzip -y \
     && wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -  \
     && sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list' \
     && apt update
RUN  apt install google-chrome-stable openjdk-8-jdk-headless -y
RUN  mkdir /tmp/dependencies
RUN  mkdir -p /opt
RUN  curl -L --silent https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.6.2.tgz > /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-5.6.2.tgz
RUN  tar -xzf /tmp/dependencies/apache-jmeter-5.6.2.tgz -C /opt
RUN  curl -L --silent https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/120.0.6099.109/linux64/chrome-linux64.zip > /tmp/dependencies/chrome-linux64.zip
RUN  unzip /tmp/dependencies/chrome-linux64.zip
RUN  mv chrome-linux64/chrome /usr/bin/google-chrome
RUN  rm -rf /tmp/dependencies

WORKDIR ${JMETER_BIN}
RUN wget -q https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/ -O ../lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar
RUN wget -q https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.3/cmdrunner-2.3.jar -P ../lib/
RUN java -cp ../lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
RUN ./PluginsManagerCMD.sh install jpgc-webdriver
RUN google-chrome --sandbox --version
RUN wget -q https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$(google-chrome --sandbox --version | grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')/chromedriver_linux64.zip || wget https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/$(google-chrome --sandbox --version | grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip
RUN unzip -j chromedriver-linux64.zip chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver chromedriver || true

# Set global PATH such that "jmeter" command is found
ENV PATH $PATH:$JMETER_BIN:$JMETER_HOME:/usr/bin

# Entrypoint has same signature as "jmeter" command
COPY entrypoint.sh /

WORKDIR ${JMETER_HOME}

ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

here is my build command:

docker build  --build-arg JMETER_VERSION=5.6.2 --build-arg -t "Jack/jmeter:latest"

And I have it tagged as:

```
docker tag Jack/jmeter jmeter
```

this is my very basic "testing.jmx" case,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.6.2">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="FTM-Random-Mixed-testing" enabled="true">
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabl
ed="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
          <elementProp name="index" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">index</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">0</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
        </collectionProp>
      </elementProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="GUI-Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" en
abled="true">
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.delayedStart">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler guiclass="com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.gui.WebDriverSamplerGui" testclass="c
om.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler" testname="jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="WebDriverSampler.script">WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get(&apos;http://jmeter-plugins.org&apos;)
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverSampler.parameters"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverSampler.language">groovy</stringProp>
        </com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig guiclass="com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.gui.ChromeDriverConfigGui" testclass=
"com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig" testname="jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.acceptinsecurecerts">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.reset_per_iteration">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.driver_path">/opt/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/bin/chromedriver</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.dev_mode">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.headless">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.maximize_browser">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="ChromeDriverConfig.additional_args"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="ChromeDriverConfig.binary_path">/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.proxy_type">SYSTEM</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.proxy_pac_url"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.http_host"></stringProp>
          <intProp name="WebDriverConfig.http_port">8080</intProp>
          <boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.use_http_for_all_protocols">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.https_host"></stringProp>
          <intProp name="WebDriverConfig.https_port">8080</intProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.ftp_host"></stringProp>
          <intProp name="WebDriverConfig.ftp_port">8080</intProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.socks_host"></stringProp>
          <intProp name="WebDriverConfig.socks_port">8080</intProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.no_proxy">localhost</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.custom_capabilites"></stringProp>
        </com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
chji@avocado:~/docker-jmeter$ cat  ~/jmeter/tcs/testing.jmx
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.6.2">
  <hashTree>
    <TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="FTM-Random-Mixed-testing" enabled="true">
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">false</boolProp>
      <boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
      <elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
        <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments">
          <elementProp name="index" elementType="Argument">
            <stringProp name="Argument.name">index</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.value">0</stringProp>
            <stringProp name="Argument.metadata">=</stringProp>
          </elementProp>
        </collectionProp>
      </elementProp>
    </TestPlan>
    <hashTree>
      <ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="GUI-Group" enabled="true">
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
        <elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
        </elementProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.delayedStart">false</boolProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
        <stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
        <boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
      </ThreadGroup>
      <hashTree>
        <com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler guiclass="com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.gui.WebDriverSamplerGui" testclass="com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler" testname="jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler" enabled="true">
          <stringProp name="WebDriverSampler.script">WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get(&apos;http://jmeter-plugins.org&apos;)
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverSampler.parameters"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverSampler.language">groovy</stringProp>
        </com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler>
        <hashTree/>
        <com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig guiclass="com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.gui.ChromeDriverConfigGui" testclass="com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig" testname="jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config" enabled="true">
          <boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.acceptinsecurecerts">true</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.reset_per_iteration">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.driver_path">/opt/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/bin/chromedriver</stringProp>
          <boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.dev_mode">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.headless">false</boolProp>
          <boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.maximize_browser">false</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="ChromeDriverConfig.additional_args"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="ChromeDriverConfig.binary_path">/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.proxy_type">SYSTEM</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.proxy_pac_url"></stringProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.http_host"></stringProp>
          <intProp name="WebDriverConfig.http_port">8080</intProp>
          <boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.use_http_for_all_protocols">true</boolProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.https_host"></stringProp>
          <intProp name="WebDriverConfig.https_port">8080</intProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.ftp_host"></stringProp>
          <intProp name="WebDriverConfig.ftp_port">8080</intProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.socks_host"></stringProp>
          <intProp name="WebDriverConfig.socks_port">8080</intProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.no_proxy">localhost</stringProp>
          <stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.custom_capabilites"></stringProp>
        </com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig>
        <hashTree/>
      </hashTree>
    </hashTree>
  </hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
```

, which sits on my local server. As you may find, I have adjust the chromdriver  and chrome value in this test case.

this is the command I have the test case executed.

```
docker run --dns="10.160.83.102" --mount type=bind,source="~/testcaseDir",target="/opt/testcases" jmeter -n -t /opt/testcases/testing.jmx -l /tmp/runtime.jtl -j /tmp/runtime.log -o /opt/web-output
```

In my case, in order to reach my website, I need to provide my DNS server.

Thanks for the help.

Jack

Answer (score 0):

Try running your container like:

```
docker run -it your-image-name-here /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/google-chrome --headless"
```

and see what will be the output, then take the necessary actions once you fix your Chrome installation JMeter should be able to launch it as well.

If you just downloaded it from this page: https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/

it might be the case you need to install some dependencies before trying to launch Chrome, here is what needs to be installed on [Ubuntu 22.04](https://ubuntu.com/blog/tag/22-04-lts)

```
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffff1b00000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffff1afb000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libnss3.so => not found
    libnssutil3.so => not found
    libsmime3.so => not found
    libnspr4.so => not found
    libdbus-1.so.3 => not found
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => not found
    libatk-bridge-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libcups.so.2 => not found
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => not found
    libdrm.so.2 => not found
    libexpat.so.1 => not found
    libxcb.so.1 => not found
    libxkbcommon.so.0 => not found
    libatspi.so.0 => not found
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007ffff1a0e000)
    libX11.so.6 => not found
    libXcomposite.so.1 => not found
    libXdamage.so.1 => not found
    libXext.so.6 => not found
    libXfixes.so.3 => not found
    libXrandr.so.2 => not found
    libgbm.so.1 => not found
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => not found
    libcairo.so.2 => not found
    libasound.so.2 => not found
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007ffff19ea000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffff17c2000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffffffc4000)
```

Going forward consider providing your [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) and JMeter [.jmx test plan](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JmxTestPlan), in other words a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) because we don't know why Chrome cannot be started in your container and your limited output doesn't tell the full story.

Here is an example Dockerfile which uses the Chrome and JMeter versions you're trying to use:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04

RUN apt update
RUN apt install wget gnupg unzip -y
RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add -
RUN sh -c 'echo "deb [arch=amd64] http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list'
RUN apt update
RUN apt install google-chrome-stable openjdk-8-jdk-headless -y
RUN wget -q https://archive.apache.org/dist/jmeter/binaries/apache-jmeter-5.6.2.tgz
RUN tar xf apache-jmeter-5.6.2.tgz
RUN wget -q https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/120.0.6099.109/linux64/chrome-linux64.zip
RUN unzip chrome-linux64.zip
RUN mv chrome-linux64/chrome /usr/bin/google-chrome
WORKDIR /apache-jmeter-5.6.2/bin
RUN wget -q https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/ -O ../lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar
RUN wget -q https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.3/cmdrunner-2.3.jar -P ../lib/
RUN java -cp ../lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
RUN ./PluginsManagerCMD.sh install jpgc-webdriver
RUN google-chrome --sandbox --version
RUN wget -q https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/$(google-chrome --sandbox --version | grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')/chromedriver_linux64.zip || wget https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/$(google-chrome --sandbox --version | grep -oE '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+')/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip
RUN unzip -j chromedriver-linux64.zip chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver chromedriver || true
RUN <<EOF cat >> test.jmx
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jmeterTestPlan version="1.2" properties="5.0" jmeter="5.6.2">
<hashTree>
<TestPlan guiclass="TestPlanGui" testclass="TestPlan" testname="Test Plan" enabled="true">
<boolProp name="TestPlan.functional_mode">false</boolProp>
<boolProp name="TestPlan.tearDown_on_shutdown">false</boolProp>
<boolProp name="TestPlan.serialize_threadgroups">false</boolProp>
<elementProp name="TestPlan.user_defined_variables" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" testname="User Defined Variables" enabled="true">
<collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
</elementProp>
</TestPlan>
<hashTree>
<ThreadGroup guiclass="ThreadGroupGui" testclass="ThreadGroup" testname="Thread Group" enabled="true">
<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.on_sample_error">continue</stringProp>
<elementProp name="ThreadGroup.main_controller" elementType="LoopController" guiclass="LoopControlPanel" testclass="LoopController" testname="Loop Controller" enabled="true">
<stringProp name="LoopController.loops">1</stringProp>
<boolProp name="LoopController.continue_forever">false</boolProp>
</elementProp>
<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.num_threads">1</stringProp>
<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.ramp_time">1</stringProp>
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.delayedStart">false</boolProp>
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.scheduler">false</boolProp>
<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>
<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.delay"></stringProp>
<boolProp name="ThreadGroup.same_user_on_next_iteration">true</boolProp>
</ThreadGroup>
<hashTree>
<com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler guiclass="com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.gui.WebDriverSamplerGui" testclass="com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler" testname="jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler" enabled="true">
<stringProp name="WebDriverSampler.script">WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
WDS.browser.get(&apos;http://jmeter-plugins.org&apos;)
System.out.println(&quot;I&apos;m too stupid for launching JMeter in Docker, I need to quit IT and become a rickshaw&quot;)
WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
</stringProp>
<stringProp name="WebDriverSampler.parameters"></stringProp>
<stringProp name="WebDriverSampler.language">groovy</stringProp>
</com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler>
<hashTree/>
<com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig guiclass="com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.gui.ChromeDriverConfigGui" testclass="com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig" testname="jp@gc - Chrome Driver Config" enabled="true">
<boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.acceptinsecurecerts">false</boolProp>
<boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.reset_per_iteration">false</boolProp>
<stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.driver_path">/apache-jmeter-5.6.2/bin/chromedriver</stringProp>
<boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.dev_mode">false</boolProp>
<boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.headless">true</boolProp>
<boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.maximize_browser">true</boolProp>
<stringProp name="ChromeDriverConfig.additional_args">--no-sandbox</stringProp>
<stringProp name="ChromeDriverConfig.binary_path"></stringProp>
<stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.proxy_type">SYSTEM</stringProp>
<stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.proxy_pac_url"></stringProp>
<stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.http_host"></stringProp>
<intProp name="WebDriverConfig.http_port">8080</intProp>
<boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.use_http_for_all_protocols">true</boolProp>
<stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.https_host"></stringProp>
<intProp name="WebDriverConfig.https_port">8080</intProp>
<stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.ftp_host"></stringProp>
<intProp name="WebDriverConfig.ftp_port">8080</intProp>
<stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.socks_host"></stringProp>
<intProp name="WebDriverConfig.socks_port">8080</intProp>
<stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.no_proxy">localhost</stringProp>
<stringProp name="WebDriverConfig.custom_capabilites"></stringProp>
</com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.config.ChromeDriverConfig>
<hashTree/>
</hashTree>
</hashTree>
</hashTree>
</jmeterTestPlan>
EOF
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-c","./jmeter.sh -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl"]
```

If you build it like:

```
docker build --platform linux/amd64 -t jmeter-webdriver .
```

and run it like:

```
docker run -it jmeter-webdriver
```

you should see one successful request.

Feel free to use it as a basis or as it is.

More information: [How to Use Docker with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-docker)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have just updated my original posting. As I was using your Docker template, I have got the same results.

Comment: You're not following my recommendations hence I'm stopping support. The first problem I can see is `<boolProp name="WebDriverConfig.headless">false</boolProp>`, as soon as you don't have any [DISPLAY](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432255/what-is-the-display-environment-variable) you need to set it to `true`. More information: [Selenium + Docker: How to Run Selenium Tests in Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/selenium-docker)

Comment: Sorry, that was my fault. I was trying to make my test case as simple as possible before presenting to you, so I have it edited it from Jmeter GUI, and tested first. I forgot to select the headless checkbox after that.  Secondly, I am not able to run such command within my created image,  "docker run -it jmeter /bin/sh -c "/usr/bin/google-chrome --headless"",   it output me the jmeter usage page, as it is for jmeter execution only.   Thanks.

Comment: First you tell me "Entrypoint has same signature as "jmeter" command" and then you complain that running image shows you JMeter usage? Amend "your" command to run "your" image to override the entrypoint to /bin/sh and you will see something different

Comment: Sorry, in my entrypoint.sh, I have something as: "jmeter $@", so within the container, , it runs this command "jmeter /bin/sh -c /usr/bin/google-chrome --headless", which is not recognized by the jmeter itself.  I have just made some adjustment, and here is the 2nd try output:  ==>  [0112/210456.319836:ERROR:icu_util.cc(240)] Invalid file descriptor to ICU data received. Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)", it seems to me the chrome is actually crashed.

Comment: Dear Jack, I've provided you the working image, I'm not your personal mentor to walk through your "updated" and "changes" and look where you made a mistake. At least not for free. I encourage you to use my Dockerfile as a basis. Also according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling) article you should always be using the latest version of JMeter so consider migrating to [JMeter 5.6.3](https://lists.apache.org/thread/o906of55x1n8z2zm8fyj3w9k3lqf8y0c)

Comment: Thanks for all the helps. They are really helpful. Appreciated !